# Execution order of async tasks on the main queue

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

In the code below the print statements execute in the order of the numbers they contains (1, 2, 3, etc.)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("4")
    }

    print("1")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("5")
    }

    print("2")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("6")
    }

    print("3")
}
```

Can you explain why execution process happens this way? Are `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillAppear` methods already in the queue when we asynchronously dispatch a block in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I'm really not sure what else you would expect... Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why isn't it: 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6? I mean why don't the dispatch blocks run right after the corresponding methods of VC life cycle?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be consecutive, if you're making asynchronous calls?

Comment: @Alexander 1, 2, 3 are consecutive since the methods they're called from belong to consecutive methods of VC life cycle. As for 4, 5, 6 - they execute one after another because of the same logic: they're added in this order in a serial queue.

Comment: @Legonaftik The "serial" part of a serial queue just means that tasks are *started* in order. By making async calls, as opposed to sync calls, you're telling the queue to not wait on the completion of one task before starting the next. Thus, your tasks are starting in the correct order, but being suspended/resumed in an unpredictable fashion that leads to the nondeterministic behaviour you're looking at

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods already in the queue when we asynchronously dispatch a block in `viewDidLoad`?

In effect: yes. They are not "in the queue", exactly, but they are already in train as part of the existing main queue code sequence.

It's all a matter of when the runloop comes to an end. Your code dispatched asynchronously to the main queue cannot run until that happens. In effect, we have to come completely to the end of this CATransaction (one "revolution" of the runloop) before `print 4` and so forth can happen.

You have probably put this logging into the root view controller. It is a special case, because your app is just launching and nothing happens until the call to `makeKeyAndVisible` is sent to the window.

At that moment `viewDidLoad` is called and `viewWillAppear` is called, in succession, as part of this one call to `makeKeyAndVisible`.

[image]

[image]

Thus, the same code is still running on the main thread; there has been no moment for your dispatched code to run. So we get `print 1` and `print 2` before anything else.

The situation with `viewDidAppear` is a little different:

[image]

As you can see, we are no longer in that call to `makeKeyAndVisible`. But the main thread is still running, because we turn immediately to any transaction completion blocks (`cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks`). It might help to think of `viewDidAppear` as being effectively the completion block to the animation in `viewWillAppear`. That has already been configured as part of the call to `viewWillAppear`, so it is still part of the same transaction. Thus `viewDidAppear` still comes right after `viewWillAppear` without pause and we get `print 3`.

*Now* at long last the launch sequence ends and your main queue asynchronous code has a chance to run, which it does in the order in which it was enqueued (`print 4`, `print 5`, `print 6`).